# MYSQL syntax conditional COUNT

Tags: mysql, syntax, count

I have a complicated joined query working.  However, in addition to pulling fields from different tables, I want to count the number of records meeting certain conditions.

For example, one of the tables is followers and I want to count how many followers a given person being followed--identified by their userid--has.  This number will not be the same as the number of records from the overall query which is about the follower with a different userid.

I am thinking there is some way to do this with the COUNT command but I am clueless to the syntax.

The following might do it with a query within a query but it is messy and I am looking for a simpler way to do it.   Thanks for any suggestions.

Table `follow_table`: `ID`, `follower_id`, `followed_id`

```
$res1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM follow_table WHERE follower_id= '$userid'");

//have list of all users this user is following
while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($res1))
{
    $followed_id = $row1['followed_id'];
    $res2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM follow_table WHERE followed_id = '$followed_id'");
    echo mysql_num_rows($res2); // Echo the number of followers
}
```

Comment: So, you want the number of followers of those you follow?

Comment: yes.  How many people total, not just you, are following that person.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    f1.followed_id                      --- all the people that $user follows
  , COUNT(*)        AS followers        --- and the number of their followers
FROM 
    follow_table AS f1
  JOIN 
    follow_table AS f2
      ON f2.followed_id = f1.followed_id
WHERE
    f2.follower_id = $userid            --- the specific $user
GROUP BY
    f1.followed_id ;
```

Comment: Worked.  Great. I don't suppose there is a way to count rows conditionally in another table, say photos, as in how many photos person followed has uploaded, as in COUNT(p.*) WHERE p.userid = f1.followed_id

Comment: There probably is but it might be complicated to do two different counts on different tables in one query. I suggest you post another question.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM follow_table ft WHERE ft.follower_id= '$userid' AND (
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM follow_table ft2
WHERE ft2.follower_id = ft.follower_id) > 0
```

If i understand you, this should help make all in one query.

Comment: not working yet. would 2nd where be f2.followed_id=ft.followed_id?  Also, to print out I modified in 2nd clause to SELECT COUNT(*) as `countfollow' and then tried to echo $row['countfollow'] but not getting a result.